# Correct approach for gathering data with jQuery Mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I need to adapt a Ruby on Rails (v2.3.12) app to gather data via a mobile web interface. We would prefer to not have to build a client app using PhoneGap, Appcelerator, etc. I've looked at the mobile web toolkits and jQuery Mobile seems to be a relatively straightforward way to do what we want to do.

We have a basic workflow/design done, as a series of single pages. The targeted users require this to be SUPER simple. I need to gather master detail data in the following manner:

- Step 1 - 2 data elements (master page)
- Step 2 - enter 2 data elements and a NEXT and a DONE button (detail page)
- Step 3 - enter data in 1-3 data elements and a NEXT button (detail page)

Once next is clicked on Step 3, we go back to Step 2 and repeat. If done, Click DONE and flow goes back to Step 1. Once DONE is clicked, I want to be able to POST all of the data back to the Rails app.

This is my first mobile app, so I'm not sure of the best approach to take to save data on those detail pages before I am finished gathering data. This may also not be an appropriate approach to take for this kind of app. Either way, I'm hoping for some guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd keep things super simple by handling the whole thing in a single form with dynamically generated inputs.

Each time the Next/Done button is pushed you hide the current set of inputs and create some new ones (using js) that are appropriately named. I'd use arrays to keep everything organized.

When all the data has been entered the form can be submitted as usual and everything gets sent off to your Rails app in one POST.

Comment: Slick - I had wondered if something as simple as that would work - thanks David!